# How to host multiple websites on GlassFish 4.0 server

Tags: web, glassfish, hosting, war, web-hosting

I have GlassFish 4.0 and I want to host tow different websites on it by uploading war files,

So I have the first website in (web1.war) and the second website in (web2.war), How can I access them using (www.web1.com) and (www.web2.com) using GlassFish 4.0 server.

Assuming for sure that (www.web1.com) and (www.web2.com) are reserved domains for me and GlassFish 4.0 is installed on a public server with a public ip.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of different things you need to configure here:

1. Acquire the domain names
2. Configure the domain names to point to the IP of the host server
3. Configure GlassFish Virtual Servers to handle requests on your domain names
4. Deploy web apps to GlassFish, choosing previously configured virtual servers

[The GlassFish 4.0 administration guide [PDF]](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf) details how to use Virtual Servers to achieve this in section 14-2 and from 14-11 onwards.

The alternative way to do this is with Apache web server, which allows you to configure VHosts based on the URL used in the request. These requests can then be proxied to GlassFish. This configuration is equivalent to using GlassFish's virtual servers feature.

Comment: Hi Mike, does the physical server machine need to have two public IPs?

Comment: @qualebs it doesn't need multiple IPs, and I can't think of a good enough reason why you might want that. Maybe there are reasons for one public and one private. Traffic can be managed via multiple domain names which point to the same IP address and web server/proxy for more advanced configuration.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have always believed for some reason that each time I register a new domain name I have to buy one more public IP for my Ubuntu virtual server machine since the `/etc/hosts` file has an IP and host entries suggesting this beliefs